# Merging two digitally signed PDFs with Zend_Pdf

Tags: php, zend-framework, pdf, digital-signature, tcpdf

Scenario: I have a webservice that signs PDFs, I'm using PHP, the Zend framework, and TCPDF. A PDF is to be submitted to the webservice, where a signature page is created, then merged with the incoming PDF, and then the merged document is signed. I've got TCPDF to create and sign the second document, but I'm not able to merge the two documents while preserving the signature.

My questions: Can TCPDF add pages to an existing PDF, then sign? Can Zend_Pdf merge two PDFs where one is already signed? Can signed PDFs even be merged? Is there a better way?

Answer (score 2):

Afaik no, signed pdfs can't be merged, cause the signature is applied to the document, not to its range. Changing the document invalidates the signature.

Comment: What I think he means is that he needs to merge two simple pdf's without signature and finally sign it. I also need that solution.

Answer (score -1):

If you are not concerned about invalidating the signature you can always print to Adobe PDF again and then combine with other PDFs.